# Breaking/exit nested for in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, nested-loops

How do I get out of nested for or loop in vb.net?

I tried using exit for but it jumped or breaked only one for loop only.

How can I make it for the following:

```
for each item in itemList
     for each item1 in itemList1
          if item1.text = "bla bla bla" then
                exit for
          end if
     end for
end for
```

Comment: What VB really needs is an `Exit For item` variant of the statement, similar to `Next item`. In the "good old days" you could explicitly `Next` the outer loop. Today, VB gives an error. Of course, it is more "constructive" to `Exit For` instead.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no `exit two levels of for` statement, but there are a few workarounds to do what you want:

- **Goto**. In general, using `goto` is [considered to be bad practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_To_Statement_Considered_Harmful) (and rightfully so), but using `goto` solely for a forward jump out of structured control statements is usually considered to be OK, especially if the alternative is to have more complicated code.

  ```
  For Each item In itemList
      For Each item1 In itemList1
          If item1.Text = "bla bla bla" Then
              Goto end_of_for
          End If
      Next
  Next

  end_of_for:
  ```
- **Dummy outer block**

  ```
  Do
      For Each item In itemList
          For Each item1 In itemList1
              If item1.Text = "bla bla bla" Then
                  Exit Do
              End If
          Next
      Next
  Loop While False
  ```

  or

  ```
  Try
      For Each item In itemlist
          For Each item1 In itemlist1
              If item1 = "bla bla bla" Then
                  Exit Try
              End If
          Next
      Next
  Finally
  End Try
  ```
- **Separate function**: Put the loops inside a separate function, which can be exited with `return`. This might require you to pass a lot of parameters, though, depending on how many local variables you use inside the loop. An alternative would be to put the block into a multi-line lambda, since this will create a closure over the local variables.
- **Boolean variable**: This might make your code a bit less readable, depending on how many layers of nested loops you have:

  ```
  Dim done = False

  For Each item In itemList
      For Each item1 In itemList1
          If item1.Text = "bla bla bla" Then
              done = True
              Exit For
          End If
      Next
      If done Then Exit For
  Next
  ```

Comment: Can't say that any of those are better than the `goto` other than the function if it actually makes sense.

Comment: I am going to use that `goto` in a big project just to remember my programming days in qbasic, ah such innocent times. otherwise i would go for a dummy do.

Comment: I prefer the `Try` / `Exit Try` approach, but I am no fan of the `goto` option.

Comment: Note that the "Boolean variable" method requires multiple variables and tests as nesting level gets deeper. This becomes fugly...

Comment: @ysap - In my experience, its rare to need multiple boolean variables. Typically, there is a single exit condition (e.g. "done") that once it is encountered, all loop levels should be exited. Nevertheless, I prefer making a separate method, and using "Return" - this cleanly encapsulates the nested construct.

Answer (score 17):

Put the loops in a subroutine and call `return`

Comment: It's worth noting that there is overhead associated with such a call that is not present in the simpler `goto` solution. Of course, if the code is reusable it should be in a function already anyway.

Comment: How can it be an overhead? @Dan

Comment: @AltianoGerung Well, my comment above assumes the compiler doesn't optimize and inline the function call. All function calls (assuming they're not inlined by the compiler) have the overhead of the prologue and epilogue to update the base stack pointer (as well as do other things like call destructors and do garbage collection if the language supports it). This is often minutia in the grand scheme of things, but does exist and can quickly become apparent in tight loops. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue

Comment: @Dan Well, that's beyond me LOL. I think with my use cases and how technology improve over time, I will never need to worry about it.

Comment: @AltianoGerung If there's anything experience has taught me, it's that with enough scale, even the smallest of problems become big enough to matter. As always, profile before you make any assumptions. :)

Answer (score 7):

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 100
    bool = False
    For j As Integer = 0 To 100
        If check condition Then
            'if condition match
            bool = True
            Exit For 'Continue For
        End If
    Next
    If bool = True Then Continue For
Next
```

Comment: Do not use this. Its behavior is wrong. Instead see accepted answer's "boolean variable" solution from six years earlier. If it were a new approach, I would explain what makes it behave incorrectly, but its not worth doing so, as the approach was already correctly shown in that earlier answer.

Answer (score 3):

Make the outer loop a while loop, and "Exit While" in the if statement.

Comment: This does the exact same thing as `goto` with more instructions, more verbosity and more indentation. What's the point?

Answer (score 3):

I've experimented with typing "exit for" a few times and noticed it worked and VB didn't yell at me. It's an option I guess but it just looked bad.

I think the best option is similar to that shared by Tobias. Just put your code in a function and have it return when you want to break out of your loops. Looks cleaner too.

```
For Each item In itemlist
    For Each item1 In itemlist1
        If item1 = item Then
            Return item1
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: No, multiple "Exit For"s *does not* result in the desired behavior. The first one exits the *first* loop, additional ones are never reached, so have no effect. Other than that suggestion, you seem to have simply repeated earlier answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to exit a for-to loop, I just set the index beyond the limit:

```
  For i = 1 To max
    some code
    if this(i) = 25 Then i = max + 1
    'some more code...
  Next
```

Comment: I recommend showing how this applies to this question. Take the code from the question, and edit it to use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a boolean value check in your loop:

```
If MyBreak Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Where MyBreak is toggled by a button or label clicked.

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the [help].