# Exit 2 for loops pressing esc button

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, exit

I am using vb.net to code. This program goes through  each pixel in a picturebox checking and compare the color that the user selected. I made a code to stop the looping when the user press ESC button on the keyboard. But it looks like the program does not stop when the the esc is pressed.

I made a messagebox to pop when the esc button is pressed. When the loop is running and I press the esc button, the messagebox pops up only when the whole loop is done.

```
For x = rect.X To endPointX - 1 Step pixelStep
    For y = endpointY - 1 To rect.Y Step -1

        If e.X >= 0 And e.Y >= 0 And (e.X < PictureBox1.Width) And (e.Y < PictureBox1.Height) Then
            If escPress  Then
                Exit For
            End If

            If bmp.GetPixel(x, y) = cor Then
                cruzNoBitmap(PictureBox1, n, pemSize, x, y)

                addRow(x, y)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If escPress Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

```
Private Sub frmBitmaps_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        If  e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
            MsgBox("test")
            escPress = True
        End If
End Sub
```

Any help I would be thankful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breaking/exit nested for in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312291/breaking-exit-nested-for-in-vb-net)

Comment: The message box is shown afterwards because that's when the `KeyDown` event has a chance to fire. Your two loops occupy the entire UI thread, meaning no other code can run until they're done. You need to move your loops into a separate thread so the UI can remain responsive. Look into _multithreading_ or the _Task Parallel Library_.

Comment: @VisualVincent What if I want to use a thread and call a sub that has parameters? 
it was like that before..to call the sub `checkColor(e)` 
with the thread: ` thread2 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf checkColor) thread2.Start() `

Comment: @Sam1996 well you can encapsulate the method call in an anonymous method: `thread2 = New System.Threading.Thread(Sub() checkColor(e))`

Comment: Why do you check `If e.X >= 0 And e.Y >= 0 And (e.X < PictureBox1.Width) And (e.Y < PictureBox1.Height) Then` every iteration? It seems that the value would be the same always (unless it's changing elsewhere during the loop but I doubt it). If that is false then neither loop should run. Check it once at the beginning of `checkColor`, or better yet, before you start the thread.

Comment: djv attention to detail is immaculate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple options. Both have the processing code run off the UI thread. The first uses a `Thread` as you suggested, but with the syntax to get you going. Code execution continues after `Thread.Start` is called. The second uses `Async/Await` which doesn't create an additional thread but still takes the processing off the UI. This is a more modern approach. Both should work for you. Instead of using your exact code, this just counts to 100 over 10 seconds.

```
Private escPress As Boolean = False

Private Sub RunThreadButton_Click(sender As Object, ea As EventArgs) Handles runThreadButton.Click
    Dim p As New Point()
    Dim thread2 = New System.Threading.Thread(Sub() checkColor(p))
    thread2.Start()
End Sub

Private Async Sub AsyncButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles asyncButton.Click
    Dim p As New Point()
    Await Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() checkColor(p))
End Sub

Private Sub EscapeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles escapeButton.Click
    escPress = True
End Sub

Private Sub checkColor(e As Point)
    Try
        For x = 0 To 9
            If escPress Then Exit For
            For y = 0 To 9
                If escPress Then Exit For
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
                Console.WriteLine(y + 10 * x + 1)
            Next
        Next
    Finally
        escPress = False
    End Try
End Sub
```

It seems like the condition

```
If e.X >= 0 And e.Y >= 0 And (e.X < PictureBox1.Width) And (e.Y < PictureBox1.Height) Then
```

is needless since that will never change unless the PictureBox width is changing mid-loop. This could be checked once prior to the loop, or could be checked prior to calling `checkColor`, which is where it should be done since you're interacting with UI, and why make a pointless call for nothing?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a *single* thread, the button function will not fire until the loops have ended.

You can confirm this by making x and y global integers, and displaying them in the messagebox.

If you want to be able to exit, you will need to create a second thread, and run the loops on that thread.

An example for multithreading can be found here: http://howtostartprogramming.com/vb-net/vb-net-tutorial-53-multithreading/

Comment: What if I want to use a thread and call a sub that has parameters?

Comment: it was like that before..to call the sub
`checkColor(e)`

with the thread:
`
thread2 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf checkColor)
            thread2.Start()
`

Comment: you can call threads with params 2 ways, but I would start a new question for that. short version. 1. create object with internal variables (use as params), then set them before you do thread.start().   2: Pass parameters directly     ' SendMailERRORNotification(DISPLAYMSG)
         *DIM   trd = New Thread(Sub() Me.MYTHREADEDSUB(param1 ))
            trd.internalparam2 = 45
            trd.internalparam3 = True
            trd.Start()*